# Linking to Multiple Taxonomies in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a page that filters something by multiple taxonomies at once—so, for example:

```
http://blog.com/category/news/tag/politics
```

to get a page of news posts about politics.

Is this even possible? (I'm not wedded to any particular URL structure)

Answer (score 2):

Version 3.1 of Wordpress introduced advanced taxonomy queries which look to do exactly what you're after.

Learn more about them here:

http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-1-advanced-taxonomy-queries/

Comment: I understand how these new queries work (and I'm actually using them), but I'm not able to map them to the URL. You can't create advanced taxonomy queries using query strings, only through arrays.

Comment: I found this article over at wordpress.stackexchange that seems to cover what you are looking for in detail: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9346/how-do-i-rewrite-a-url-to-use-taxonomy-instead-of-category-when-multiple-taxo